# How return data only when relation exist?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this query:

```
$result = Transaction::with("items", "results")->get();
```

How return data from `Transactions` only when exist data in relation `results`?

Comment: I guess, I need `whereHas`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use **has** method

```
$result = Transaction::has('results')->with("items", "results")->get();
```